# Is $SU(n)$ a complex Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, unitary-matrices, complex-manifolds

I had been naively thinking that $GL_n(\mathbb C)$,$SL_n(\mathbb C)$,$U_n(\mathbb C)$ and $SU_n(\mathbb C)$ being the complex analogs of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ etc should be complex Lie groups.

But wiki says that while $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is indeed a complex Lie group, $SU_n(\mathbb C)$ is not.

> 1. What makes the general linear group a complex Lie group but the special unitary group not one?

> 2. What can be said about the special linear and unitary group over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: 1. The definition of a Lie group. Although $SU_n(\Bbb C)\subseteq GL_n(\Bbb C)$, it is not a complex Lie group, i.e., multiplication and inverse are not complex differentiable - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Lie_group).

Comment: I know the lie algebra is the trace zero skew hermitian matrices. So the dimension of that space will be $n^2 -1$? Okay that seems like a way to immediately say that it is not a complex lie group. But can one give a more topological answer? Or is it the case that any 2n dim matrix real Lie group is actually a complex lie group? and dimension argument is the only way?

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person you are correct that $SU_n(\mathbb{C})$ is of real dimension $n^2-1$. The necessary condition is indeed that the real dimension has to be even. But note that for odd $n$, the dimension $n^2-1$ is even. However $SU_n(\mathbb{C})$ is never a complex Lie group. General case requires a more sophisticated argument.

Comment: Wikipedia: A ''complex Lie group'' is a Lie group over the complex numbers; i.e., it is a *complex manifold* that is also a group in such a way that $G \times G \to G, (x, y) \mapsto x y^{-1}$ is *holomorphic*. And, is this true for $SU_n(\Bbb C)$? Which justification do you have for saying, "naively it should be"? I don't see this.

Comment: What about $SL_n$? Here we do get even real dim. But how can we say/not say it is a complex lie group?

Comment: @DietrichBurde You are right. I was naively replacing $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$ in my head and hoping it would work out. It seems to be much more complicated than that.

Comment: For $SL_n$ we also can consider the "complexification", see for example the answers to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330099/relationship-between-real-lie-groups-algebras-complex-lie-groups-algebras-and-c?rq=1).